# Como puedo validar el login mediante php y vuejs?

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Estoy realizando el login y funciona cuando el usuario y la contrasena son correctos ya que mediante php redirecciono a la pagina y listo, pero como puedo mostrar un mensaje en el formulario de que la contrasena o el usuario son incorrectos mediante js?

aqui el codigo:

php:

```
public static function login () {
    $user = Clear::Clearvars($_POST["user"]);
    $pass = Clear::Clearvars($_POST["pass"]);
    $query = Model::login($user, $pass);
    if (is_array($query)) {
        Controller::renderview("admin_panel");
    }else{
        "Error";
    }
}
```

vista:

```
 <section class = "form_login">
            <h1>Welcome admin</h1>
            <form action="index.php?url=login" method="post">
                <input class = "inputs" type="text" name="user" v-model = "user" placeholder = "User">
                <input class = "inputs" type="text" name="pass" v-model = "pass" placeholder ="Password">
                <button class="login_button">Login</button>
            </form>
        </section>
```

js:

```
login: function () {
        axios.post('index.php?url=login',{'user':this.user,'pass':this.pass}).then(response =>{
           console.log(response.data);
        },function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras mandar el error por medio de json_encode

```
public static function login () {
    $user = Clear::Clearvars($_POST["user"]);
    $pass = Clear::Clearvars($_POST["pass"]);
    $query = Model::login($user, $pass);
    if (is_array($query)) {
        Controller::renderview("admin_panel");
    }else{
        echo: json_encode("Error contraseña o usuario incorrectos";
    }
}
```

js

```
    export default {
     data() {
       return {
         error: ""
       }
     },
methods: {
    login: function () {
            axios.post('index.php?url=login',{'user':this.user,'pass':this.pass}).then(response =>{
               console.log(response.data);
            },function(response) {
                this.error = response 
            }
        )
        }
}
    }
```

vista

```
 <section class = "form_login">
            <h1>Welcome admin</h1>
            <h2>{{ error }}</h2>
            <form action="index.php?url=login" method="post">
                <input class = "inputs" type="text" name="user" v-model = "user" placeholder = "User">
                <input class = "inputs" type="text" name="pass" v-model = "pass" placeholder ="Password">
                <button @click="login();" class="login_button">Login</button>
            </form>
        </section>
```